# PHPUnit and Extended Classes

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I am curious, I have a base class - called `Base` and a controller class called  - `Controller` - apparently you cannot test controller - in netbeans - because it cannot find Base class.

```
class Controller extends Base{}
class Base{}
```

netbeans will generate tests for Base but not for controller. Is this because A) every test must extend PHP unit and B) if you test the logic in Base and everything passes it's safe to assume that controller will too? - seems rather untrustworthy.

What does one do in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must include the file or you can use an autoload (check the autoload of composer. PSR-0 or classmap).
And preferably use phpunit.xml passing this autoload or bootstrap for automated testing. (no need to stay including all files that will be tested in the test file).

Comment: You should also have each class in its own file, and then test each class individually.  The smaller objects will help keep the logic separated, and make for easier testing.

Comment: Yes, this is the first step after that will come the automated tests using phpunit.xml, autoload and namespaces.